# Throw Expressions not working for Boolean expressions?

Tags: c#, throw, c#-7.0

Throw Expressions work in this case:

```
string myStr;

public MyObj( string myStr ) =>
    this.myStr = myStr ?? throw new ArgumentNullException( "myStr" );
```

But why doesn't this compile too?

```
bool isRunning;

public void Run() =>
    isRunning = !isRunning || throw new InvalidOperationException( "Already running" );
```

Comment: Because the proposal was specific to the null coalescing operator and not the logical or operator. https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.0/throw-expression.md

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[From the original proposal on github](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.0/throw-expression.md):

> A *throw expression* is permitted in only the following syntactic contexts:
>
> - As the second or third operand of a ternary conditional operator `?:`
> - As the second operand of a null coalescing operator `??`
> - As the body of an expression-bodied lambda or method.

These are the only three cases where throw expressions can be used. Thus your use of a throw in a boolean expression isn't covered and isn't valid syntax.

Comment: Thanks! So I [requested Throw Expressions to work in more cases](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/918).

Comment: @HappyNomad: You don't need it to work in more cases. You can say `isRunning = isRunning ? throw ... : true;`, done. Though frankly, you would be better to simply write the code sensibly: `if (isRunning) throw ... ; isRunning = true;` is just fine.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks, I know. But why introduce Throw Expressions if only partially?

Comment: @EricLippert Actually, I'm not sure about `&&`. Perhaps it's best not to touch Boolean expressions after all.

Comment: @HappyNomad: if your question is "what were the factors considered by the design team?" then *read the design team notes* and the github discussion forum.

Comment: @EricLippert Any specific links you'd like to share?

Comment: @EricLippert Only you know specifically what you are referring to. A quick Google search doesn't turn up anything relevant. Shouldn't this kind of thing be documented in actual docs rather than having to comb the web?  If you don't want to share then basically your answer is "go find it" and if you can't then tough luck.

Comment: @HappyNomad: Go to github. Search for the C# project. Do a search in that project for "throw expression".  Find the meeting notes. Read them.

Comment: @EricLippert Github's built-in search engine sucks. After crafting a sufficient [Google query](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Agithub.com%2Fdotnet%2Fcsharplang+meetings+throw+expressions), I finally found [this](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2016/LDM-2016-10-18.md).  But regarding Throw Expressions, it only says, "They are allowed as expression bodies, as the second operand of ??, and as the second and third operand of ?:. They are not allowed in && and ||, and cannot be parenthesized. We think this is a fine place to land."

Comment: @EricLippert This certainly doesn't answer the question, as you phrased it, "what were the factors considered by the design team?"

Comment: @HappyNomad: If you're unsatisfied with the commentary by the design team then take it up with them; there's nothing I can do about it. I haven't been on the design team for five years. My point is that if that's what you want to know, asking here isn't the way to find out.  Hang out at github if you want to find out about the C# design process.

Comment: Well, this is a good example why these questions aren't really productive.

Comment: @Will Asking this here and on Github was productive. Another answer tried applying Boolean logic with the throw expression. This exposed the fundamental issue. That poster deleted his answer, but I did record what I learned in my own answer below.

Comment: @HappyNomad I read your issue over on GitHub, that was much more productive than this. I'm with Eric (ooo, tingles).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, "because the spec says I can't".  But the more interesting question is, why does the spec say that?  In short, I think it's because it would mess up Boolean logic.  A throw expression doesn't have a Boolean value.  Throw expressions are just a shortcut in syntax.  We can only get away with it when the throw expression's return value, or lack thereof, doesn't matter.  For Boolean logic to work, on the other hand, the return value *does* matter.